# Pyserial cannot send all characters to arduino, but can do it on another PC terminal

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am working on an existing project.
Until now, a PC software controls an Arduino Due.
The PC software sends serial commands to the Arduino Due.

What I am trying to do, is to replace the PC software with a python script. Python 3.5.
So I am working with `pyserial`.

The problem seems to be that the python script does not send all the characters to the Arduino Due. It misses some final characters.

The difficult parts to understand are the following:

1. When I am sending the characters, from the python script, to another PC terminal instead of the Arduino, then I can successfully collect all the characters from the terminal, I am using Bray's terminal.
2. When I am sending the same string from my terminal to the Arduino Due, the Arduino Due successfully collects the data sent.
   It seems as if only the Python to Arduino does not work, while
   Python to PC termimal is working and
   PC terminal to Arduino is working

I open the serial port like this:

```
    my_port = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)
    while connected != True:
        if my_port.is_open == 1:
            connected = True
```

Can anyone provide any insight?
Thanks.

edit: I just noticed that when the python script sends the data, then the debug serial port I am using sends corrupted data.

Comment: Are you maybe sending the characters too fast? You might want to put pauses between the characters that you send. You wouldn't be able to type them that fast at a terminal. 115Kib/s is very fast for a serial connection. If that is the speed it wants, you are clearly not overwhelming the serial port, but you might be overwhelming the program on the other side of it.

Comment: The python program sends data automatically and I want it to be fast.

Comment: I understand that you want it to be fast, but do you really need to send more than 10,000 characters per second? That is what 115.2Kib/s means, at 8 data bits, one start bit, one stop bit and one parity bit. And I wasn't suggesting that the Python program not send the data automatically, just not in such a fast burst.

Comment: No you are right, it does not have to be fast, but since I am developing a version that should run with the old version, which I cannot change, I must stick with 115200.

Comment: How many conductors does your serial cable have? If it isn't full RS232 then you are relying on software handshake and that could easily lead to characters being lost at high speeds.

Comment: Hi, I am not having any DTR/DSR and I am not using any handshaking at all.

Comment: Then at that speed losing characters at the end of a fast burst is normal. That it hasn't happened to you before was just luck.

Comment: The machine is working for many months now without such problems.

Comment: As you have discovered, you were not comparing like with like.

Comment: Correct, even though at some point I added some delays between the connection and the sending, it didn't work. As I see now, it needs a lot more time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, up to now you have been using terminal emulator programs. Even in full duplex they will normally not send a character until they have seen the echo back from the previous one. Anything more goes into the typeahead buffer. That limits the throughput substantially no matter what the baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I noticed that the debug serial was also sending less characters and I thought that there maybe a reset going on.

So I am now sending my arrays from a thread after each button press.
What I was doing, is that I was sending it directly after connection.